# How to get the default gateway of a router where I connected using C#?

Tags: c#, gateway

I can't figure out how to get it. I googled a lot since yesterday and I do not found any answer.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` until you find the one you want, then look at `GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses`.

Comment: Thanks, I have an Idea now